# JDBC From Informix to Spark using Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, informix

I can connect to the Informix database using simple JDBC connection program but when I try to load the tables using Spark Dataframes I am facing an exception. Do we need to use a specific connector for Informix spark connection?

Below is the stack trace of the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "table_name"
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:482)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxChar.toLong(IfxChar.java:666)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.getLong(IfxResultSet.java:1123)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.getNext(JDBCRDD.scala:411)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(JDBCRDD.scala:472)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: please paste your spark submit command and exception stack

Comment: @ShawnGuo: the exception stack trace has been added, but not the Spark submit command.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, I understand an eclipse to be a period of darkness, and it indicates how much I know about Eclipse; I can spell Java — c, o, f, f, e, e; and sparks are small incandescent flashes of hot material: none of which helps me assemble it into a coherent mechanism for accessing an Informix database.  Je ne sais quoi, etc.  Sorry, I can't help much.

Comment: I am accessing Informix data in spark via standalone Java program in eclipse @ShawnGuo

Comment: From stack trace it seems that there is connection to Informix database. The problem probably is with reading data from Informix. Spark calls `getNext()` which calls `getLong()` and `getLong()` recives 'table_name' which cannot be parsed as number.

Answer (score 5):

When Spark generates the database queries, it puts the column names in quotes. To accommodate this, in the JDBC connection URL you need to add

`DELIMIDENT=Y`

Comment: I know it's a late reply. But it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From stack trace it seems that there is connection to Informix database.

The problem probably is with reading data from Informix. Spark calls `getNext()` which calls `getLong()` and `getLong()` recives '*table_name*' which cannot be parsed as a number.

I don't know Spark. Maybe add some details (proably code) about how do you use Spark.